# c++ SDL how to create a vector from point a to b

Tags: c++11, sdl-2

I've made an Object called Player and an Object called Zombie, I would like to add a shooting function for Player, and the bullet to go from point Player to the point where I am holding my mouse, how can this be achived?

Comment: Calculate the pixel distance between the cursor and your player. Determine the appropriate slope of the path of the bullet and pick an arbitrary velocity. Move the bullet a certain `x` down and a certain `y` down (y/x should match the slope). I'm assuming you only care about a linear path.

Answer (score 0):

Let's eliminate the other directions first and just imagine that the direction is from left to right.
You first need to get the mouse's position which is possible by using

```
SDL_GetMouseState(int* placeX, int* placeY)
```

this pushes the mouses's x location to *placeX* and the mouses's y location to *placeY*.

Now you also need to get the position of the player, this could be done by getting the player's texture's rect while in the loop.
So if the character is at

> (x,y) (0, 10)

with a

> (w, h) (20, 40)

and you have the bullet source right at the middle-right of the character, then that makes it at

> (20, 20)

then the actual current  bullet source is at

> (x, y) -> (20, 30) (basically rect.x + bulletsource.x and rect.y +
>   bulletsource.y).

Now all you have to do is something like

```
if(bullet.x < placeX)//this makes it look like the bullet is moving to the right
{
bullet.x++ //this moves the bullet closer to the right
Redraw bullet //you have to redraw to see the changes
}
```

do the same thing for y, it doesn't really have to be an if statement.

The same logic applies when you have multiple bullet directions.

You just have to think of the bullet's source as the center of the x and y axis and check if the mouseclick is within a certain quadrant (diagonal) or near the line of an axis(straight bullet).

Once you know what quadrant or line the mouse is at, then you just change the texture to be used(diagonal bullet facing north-east or just a plain ol' simple bullet facing the north).

Comment: Thanks! But doesn't that really only apply for 45 degrees? If I am trying to shoot something let's say 12 degrees relative to the player, wouldn't the bullet just rise 45 degrees until the placeY is correct then just move directly the the right?

Comment: You could alter your code to make it move seamlessly diagonally towards that 12 degrees + location. You're going to need some math with that :).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for the help, but I solved it by using atan2, and calculated the angle. When I had the angle I just added the value of speed * cos(angle) to the x variable and speed * sin(angle) to the y variable.